# Is there a difference in reliability between these sum functions?

Tags: vba, excel

So the other day I was getting some strange sum values and I was completely stumped. I gave up on using a sum function in VBA and just added the values the long way (through loops), but then I read somewhere that using the sum functions in VBA isn't always reliable for developers? (I can't find the post anymore, but I'm still looking for it).

Is there any truth to this? I know many people have different ways to get the sum from a range of cells - without being *too opinionated*, which one of these will return the most exact result?

```
Sub testsums()

Dim metric1 As Integer, metric2 As Integer, metric3 As Integer

metric1 = Application.Sum(Range(("A1"), ("Z1")))

metric2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(("A1"), ("Z1")))

metric3 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(("A1"), ("Z1")))

End Sub
```

I'm working to reproduce my error - basically when looping through many rows (15,000+) and getting sums, some were returning zeroes where they shouldn't have been.

Comment: As far as the *result* is concerned, there is no difference.

Comment: Also, I think metric2 and metric3 are the same. VBA will assume `WorksheetFunction.` is `Application.WorksheetFunction`

Comment: The only difference between these is error handling.  Application.Sum() will be different than WorksheetFunction.Sum().  If you google those two together, you get multiple hits going into the error handling.  As @CallumDA said, WorksheetFunction.Sum() is the same as Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum() in regard to what VBA sees.

Comment: @Cyril actually there's more to it than the error handling.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the clarification (looked at your post).  I didn't think to bring up what cause the differences for a comment, but you seem to have got it all (early versus late bound).  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Application.Sum(Range(("A1"), ("Z1")))`

  That's a late-bound call against `Excel.Application`, resolved at **run-time**; as with any late-bound call (e.g. against `Object` or `Variant`), you get no IntelliSense, no auto-completion, and no compile-time validation, be it for typos in the name or for order or number of parameters. If the call is invalid or the function otherwise results in an error, this will **return** an `Error` value that you can validate with the `IsError` VBA function (of course if there's a typo in the function name what you'll get is a run-time error #438 "Object doesn't support this property or method").

  What makes this syntax work is the fact that the `Excel.Application` COM interface has a flag that makes it *extensible* - I'm not sure if it's extended with straight-up `WorksheetFunction` interface or if it's merely doubling-up the members, but anyway that's what's going on: you're calling members that don't exist on the `Application` interface at compile-time.
- `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(("A1"), ("Z1")))`

  That's an early-bound call against `Excel.WorksheetFunction`, resolved at **compile-time**; you get IntelliSense, auto-completion, and compile-time validation. A typo will fail to compile, as will missing required parameters. If the call is invalid or the function otherwise results in an error, this will **raise** a VBA run-time error that you can handle with an `On Error` statement using standard, VBA-idiomatic error handling.
- `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(("A1"), ("Z1")))`

  That's exactly the same as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum`, except it's not fully-qualified. If your project has a `WorksheetFunction` class, or if there's a `WorksheetFunction` object variable in scope, it will take precedence over a fully-qualified `Application.WorksheetFunction` call as far as resolution goes (which may result in compile errors). Otherwise, identical.

---

Which one is "more reliable" depends on exactly what you deem "reliable". Personally I consider compile-time resolution completely worth it, so the "most reliable" would be the fully-qualified early-bound version.

Comment: Always appreciate the depth to your answers - good for OP and the rest of use too!